# changing the default database for locate and mlocate

Tags: linux, locate

I  managed to run `locate` and `mlocate` so that it uses an encrypted partition, i.e. my home folder. See this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20821/using-locate-on-an-encrypted-partition).

However, how do I make the new, relocated `mlocate.db` database the default?

I now rely on the option `-d` i.e.:

```
mlocate -d ~/var/mlocate.db the_file_i_want.txt
```

But it would be great if I could avoid using the `-d` option altogether.

Answer (score 0):

From `man locate`:

```
FILES
       /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
              The database searched by default.

ENVIRONMENT
       LOCATE_PATH
              Path to additional databases, added after the default database or the databases specified using the --database option.
```

So it seems you can only get this effect if you *don't* already have a /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db file.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. If I don't use the -d option, then locate will not show me files from my home folder. It reverts to  /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db Note that echo $LOCATE_PATH gives the correct path:  /home/myhome/var/mlocate.db  .....

Answer (score 0):

use an alias in whatever you shell startup script is. For example -

```
alias locate="locate --database=$HOME/var/mlocate.db"
```

Comment: alas, I could not get this to work, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple: I added this to `.bashrc`

```
export LOCATE_PATH="$HOME/var/mlocate.db"
```

Then run a new instance of bash, and all is fine!